# GridSpec on Seaborn Subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I currently have 2 subplots using seaborn:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.apionly as sns

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

sns.distplot(df['Difference'].values, ax=ax1) #array, top subplot

sns.boxplot(df['Difference'].values, ax=ax2, width=.4) #bottom subplot
sns.stripplot([cimin, cimax], color='r', marker='d') #overlay confidence intervals over boxplot

ax1.set_ylabel('Relative Frequency') #label only the top subplot

plt.xlabel('Difference')

plt.show()
```

Here is the output:

[image: Distribution Plot]

I am rather stumped on how to make ax2 (the bottom figure) to become shorter relative to ax1 (the top figure). I was looking over the GridSpec (http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) documentation but I can't figure out how to apply it to seaborn objects.

**Question:**

1. How do I make the bottom subplot shorter compared to the top
   subplot?
2. Incidentally, how do I move the plot's title "Distrubition of Difference" to  go above the top
   subplot?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: why does seaborn cause a problem with gridspec? You will get axes objects from gridspec or subplot2grid as well. Regarding your 2nd question: did you try `ax1.xaxis.set_label_position("top")` ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I ended up using fig.suptitle('bold figure suptitle', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @dnalow mentioned, `seaborn` has no impact on `GridSpec`, as you pass a reference to the `Axes` object to the function. Like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

gridkw = dict(height_ratios=[5, 1])
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw=gridkw)

sns.distplot(tips.loc[:,'total_bill'], ax=ax1) #array, top subplot
sns.boxplot(tips.loc[:,'total_bill'], ax=ax2, width=.4) #bottom subplot

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I had a hard time because I couldn't figure out how to translate what you got from

Comment: f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

Comment: I edited the answer to show how you can set the height ratios using the `plt.subplots` command and avoid the more verbose `GridSpec` layout.

Comment: @mwaskom nice, I didn't know that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) (either directly or through something like [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot), which uses it indirectly), then you can pass `gridspec_kws`.

Here is an example using a `catplot`, where "var3" has two values, i.e. there are two subplots, which I am displaying at a ratio of 3:8, with un-shared x-axes.

```
g = sns.catplot(data=data, x="bin", y="y", col="var3", hue="var4", kind="bar", 
                sharex=False,
                facet_kws={
                  'gridspec_kws': {'width_ratios': [3, 8]}
                })

# Make the first subplot have a custom `xlim`:
g.axes[0][0].set_xlim(right=2.5)
```

Result, with labels hidden because I just copied my actual data's output, so the labels wouldn't make sense.

[image: Output of plot]